# Can I have a fully polymorphic function?

Tags: haskell, types

Would it be possible to have a completely type ambiguous function? Would the function have a type signature like:

```
Poly :: a -> a
```

where a is a type variable, like the syntax used with a type constructor declaration or typeclass requirement?

```
data TypeConstructor a = One | Two a
Func :: Num a => a -> a
```

Would it be possible to make a ubiquitous `id` function that always returns it's own value without having to know what value constructors are in use?

```
id :: a -> a
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `myId x = x`

Comment: My mind is blown. So in haskell you don't need to worry about all that like in C++?

Comment: It's a standard function. See [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:id) for the Prelude implementation. Also in the future if you're wondering about a particular type signature, you can search in on Hoogle, [like this](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+a).

Comment: @AthanClark Yes.  The compiler figures all of that out on its own thanks to Hindley Milner type inference.  If you look in the Prelude you will see that this is exactly how `id` is defined.

Comment: @AthanClark You could do this in C++ `template < typename T> T id(const T& i){return i;}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like others have said, Haskell functions are automatically polymorphic by default if they don't use any concrete features of the underlying type.  If you open up `ghci` and type:

```
>>> let f x = x
```

... then ask it the type of `f`, it will automatically infer that `f` is completely polymorphic:

```
>>> :type f
f :: t -> t
```

Same thing if you use a file.  You can just define:

```
f x = x
```

... and the compiler will infer that `f` has type `a -> a`.  You can also explicitly annotate `f`, too:

```
f :: a -> a
f x = x
```

Comment: You can, but it would involve a bottom: `poly _ = let r = r in r`.